# Swift Language Version is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift Ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an Ionic project in Xcode, but when i build the project it throws an error "Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift".

Solution is to select a swift version in build target, i see the option "swift 3" but if i select it nothing happens. There is another thing, even if i select deployment target as Ios 10.3 (default is 11), after building it i get a warning that target 11 is not available, even though i selected 10.3. Does anybody has any ideas?

Also, if i search for "SWIFT_VERSION" in the project, i see about 5 files that have verison 5 hardcoded in them.

Things i tried: Selecting swift version 3, manually searching for "SWIFT_VERSION" in every file and manually replacing swift version 5 with 3. Xcode version 8.3

Thanks

Comment: first of all, upgrade your Xcode version to the latest(12.3 or 12.4) then try to rebuild your project

Comment: that was the problem, works fine on Xcode 12.3

Comment: great you can upgrade my comment